How to implement circuit-level noise model?
I am currently trying to implement circuit-level noise on some quantum codes. Right now, I can encode the logical qubit by projecting the physical qubits into a +/-1 eigenstate of all the stabilizers using Tableau.from_stabilizers(). Then, I can convert the tableau to a circuit using Tableau.to_circuit(). Now, I want to be able to add noise to each gate that was used. How can I go backwards in the encoded circuit to apply noise to each operation? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Stim doesn't provide add-noise-to-circuit methods, due to the sheer variety in what kinds of noise people want creating a ratchet that would slowly turn those methods into complexity monsters.
The absolute simplest thing you could do is to iterate over the circuit, appending DEPOLARIZE1 on the same targets as each non-annotation gate. But you probably want to then do things like DEPOLARIZE2 for two qubit gates, idling noise for qubits not touched between two TICK instructions, and different noise strengths for different gates. Depending on your use case you might further want to implement not adding noise into certain debugging areas, using different noise strengths at different qubits or at different times, using biased noise like PAULI_CHANNEL_1, heralded noise like HERALDED_ERASE, etc, etc, etc.
